# How can I Differentiate $ y = x^{2/3} $ using first principles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I Differentiate $ y = x^{2/3} $ using first principles

Using the normal rule to find derivative, I got:

$dy/dx = ⅔x^{-⅓}$

I don't understand the first principles method. Someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Most likely, you're supposed to use $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman thanks for the swift reply. I tried using it. I just don't understand how to apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
\lim_{z\to x}\frac{z^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{z-x}
$$
You can write the numerator as
$$
(z^{1/3}-x^{1/3})(z^{1/3}+x^{1/3})
$$
and the denominator as
$$
(z^{1/3}-x^{1/3})(z^{2/3}+z^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3})
$$
so the limit is
$$
\lim_{z\to x}\frac{z^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{z-x}=
\lim_{z\to x}\frac{z^{1/3}+x^{1/3}}{z^{2/3}+z^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{(x+\Delta x)^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{\Delta x}$$

Observe that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

By letting $a=(x+\Delta x)^{2/3}$ and $b=x^{2/3}$, what would you get?

Comment: why we use the sum and difference of cubes?